# In App Purchase Server Model using Titanium

Tags: iphone, titanium, in-app-purchase

Anybody have an example of Apple inapp purchase server product model using titanium?
is it possible using titanium?

I have a already built titanium book reading app , client need to modify this like subscription purchase model, using in App purchase.

Help is highly appreciable

Answer (score 0):

You need a module to use in-app purchases in your app, it's free, download it from the marketplace https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/794?535309142